# SAS Univariate put all tests into 1 table

Tags: sas, distribution

I have the following code for computing a variety of tests

```
proc univariate data=Work.SortTempTableSorted;
    ODS select "Goodness of Fit";
    var price_change_sd;

    histogram price_change_sd / normal(mu=est sigma=est)
                                gamma(alpha=est sigma=est theta=0)
                                lognormal(sigma=est theta=0 zeta=est)
                                weibull(c=est sigma=est theta=0);
    by has_activity;
run;
```

Which essentially runs a test of distributions on a variable partitioned by the flag "has_activity". The output here is a series of tables, which I need to manually scroll through until I find what I need.

I am wondering if I can somehow output all of the results of the tests into a single table and scroll through it. I know I can specify "OUTTABLE" but this only has the results for the normal distribution.

Comment: There's a PERSIST option on the ODS OUTPUT statement that allows you to stack ODS output for BY variables if it doesn't automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. Use `ods output GoodnessOfFit;` instead. Take a look at this example using sashelp.cars. This produces a single table with all goodness of fit estimates.

```
proc univariate data=sashelp.cars;
    var horsepower;

    histogram horsepower / normal(mu=est sigma=est)
                           gamma(alpha=est sigma=est theta=0)
                           lognormal(sigma=est theta=0 zeta=est)
                           weibull(c=est sigma=est theta=0);

    by make;

    ods output GoodnessOfFit;
run;
```

Comment: that still gave me every table and plot separately. I really just want to output all of the test results into a single table, and then sort by best fit, for each grouping.

Comment: Check your WORK library for a table called "GoodnessOfFit." All tests and groups are in that table.